# Implement method calling without parentheses

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, language-design, lexical-analysis

My current project (Just a toy-language really) is a functional scripting language. And I would like to allow method calling without the need for parentheses for grouping.

```
sum 1 2 3
```

Here's the catch, and I'm not sure if this is a common thing or not, to be honest. But in my language, a method can define parameters that proceed the identifier.

```
def (a) plus (b)
    a + b
end
```

Which would end up being

```
1 plus 2
```

But what if I was using variables/functions for those parameters?
How would I know, for example, that "plus" is the method I'm calling and  not "getnum" in the following

```
getnum plus 2
```

And further more, how do I know that getnum is a parameter of plus and not the other-way-around? (Is it simply by checking parameter signatures?)
EDIT: I just repeated myself. Oops.

And lastly, should a lexer do something special for this kind of thing? If so, how would IT know which one to call the "methodtoken"? Or does the lexer just pump stuff like "Identifiertoken" and "literaltoken" out and leave it up to the runtime to figure out that it's a method call?

Comment: Even worse, what if `getnum` and `plus` are *both* functions?  In general, sounds like you'd have an ambiguous grammar.

Comment: What I mean is, if you have `def f (x)` and `def (x) g`, then what should `f g` resolve to?

Comment: I guess nested function calls would have to use parentheses (or some other set of grouping characters) unless it could determine based on the fact that getnum takes no parameters.

Comment: I guess you'd have to establish operator precedence to define which operator goes first. Same way that `1 + 2 * 3` works in math without the paretheses.

Comment: Perhaps I should support it the same way as other functional languages. Somewhat strictly. To be honest, it'd probably end up less readable using only spaces anyway. ;)

Comment: This is not a lexical analysis problem. It is a parsing problem. The lexer wouldn't know which identifier to call "methodtoken". It just pumps out stuff like "Identifiertoken" and "literaltoken". The parser has to figure out whether it is a method call.

Comment: @Aadit Indeed, and in fact it is more than a parsing problem, it is a semantic-feedback problem. The parser would have to know that any given identifier was a function name, would then have to look up how many parameters it had, and proceed accordingly. Provided all functions are declared before use it is doable, but it would be generally considered poor language design. The meaning of the program would vary according to the definitions of external (or previously declared) functions.

Comment: The way I had it in my head was to parse everybody and then run another pass to resolve this kind-of thing.

Comment: @RoyalPotato You can't accomplish much in the way of parsing if you can't even establish a correct parse tree for a function call. You can do it in one pass *if* you can suitably constrain the problem. You're finding out why the parentheses are needed, or some equivalent (`CALL identifier USING expr1[, ...]`). You need to also consider that the resulting language will be just as unintelligible to humans as it is to the parser.

Comment: @EJP: "*The meaning of the program would vary according to the definitions of external (or previously declared) functions.*" - btw, that's exactly how Haskell works :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a parsing problem. However, the bigger problem is that your language is not [syntax-directed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax-directed_translation). This means that the syntax of your language doesn't match its semantics. For example, consider the following program in your language:

```
f g
```

This can be parsed in one of two ways, `f` applied to `g` or `g` applied to `f`. However, the syntax of the language doesn't make it apparent which one of the two parse trees will be generated. As [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) correctly mentioned, "it is more than a parsing problem, it is a semantic-feedback problem".

So, how to you make your language syntax-directed? Let's take a cue from object-oriented languages. For example:

```
1 plus 2
```

In an object-oriented language like JavaScript this might be written as:

```js
Number.prototype.plus = function (n) {
    return this + n;
};

var sum = (1) .plus (2);

alert(sum);
```

Comparing the syntax of the two languages we see that the only major difference is the dot in front of the identifier `plus`. That's all we need to make your language syntax-directed. Now, you can have normal functions:

```
.sum 1 2 3
```

However, you can also have syntax-directed infix functions:

```
1 .plus 2
```

Now, the following expressions are no longer ambiguous:

```
.f g
f .g
```

However, you would still need parenthesis to disambiguate some expressions:

```
(.getnum) .plus 2
```

This is because `getnum` is called before `plus` is applied to it. It means `plus(getnum(), 2)`. On the other hand `getnum .plus 2` would mean `plus(getnum, 2)` which would be an error because you can't apply `plus` to a function.

Think of the dot as the "apply" operator of your language. Using the dot even allows you to have higher order functions:

```
1 .(true .plus-or-minus) 2
```

This is the same as `plus-or-minus(true)(1, 2)`.

---

Another alternative is to quote the data like they do in Lisp. This syntax is a lot less noisy:

1. Normal function application, `sum 1 2 3`.
2. Infix function application, `1 plus 2`.
3. Quoted identifiers, `f 'g` means `f` applied to `g` and `'f g` means `g` applied to `f`.
4. Quoted function application, `'getnum' plus 2` where `'getnum'` is implicitly quoted.
5. Higher order function application, `1 (true plus-or-minus) 2`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So basically the period/quotes specify who we're calling?

Comment: ...And when required (Like in nested function calls) we can just fallback to the use of parentheses?

Comment: Also, sorry for probably seeming clueless. Language-design is one of the many computer science/software fields that interests me, so even though I'm not into college yet, I thought I'd play around with it;). Don't tell me I'm to inexperienced/uneducated to do this, because it's my time and I can waste it however I see fit :p.

Comment: Yes, the periods mark the function and the quotes mark the data. You can always fall back to parentheses/quotes for nested function calls.

Comment: I wouldn't discourage you from learning about computer science or compilers. In fact, it's great that you're learning about programming languages at such an early age. If you are really keen about learning about compilers then you should read the [dragon book](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/lehre/ccfl/Material/ALSUdragonbook.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the book. I see people referencing it all the time, but could never find it myself. But is it actually _legal_ to use it in this form?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [operator precendence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_operator_notation) and [operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). In case of parenthesis-less method calling, the blank space is the function application operator.

[Mixfix expressions](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/handle/11303/2630) complicate this a bit, but after all you just have to develop some rules for your language and disallow some ambiguous expressions. In your example, you'd declare `plus` as an infix operator, and give all infix operators higher precedence than prefix operators.

This is the job of the parser, not the tokenizer or lexer.

Comment: So then my lexer would be allowed to go-ahead and parse identifier/literal tokens in such-places? As of this moment, that's the way my current implementation stands. But then I stopped, and wondered how the heck I would resolve a method call (just pretend the parentheses and commas are spaces) like this "method(method2(123), somevariable)". The only way I could think of was to spend the time to check validity of parameters/parameter counts. Is that the only way? I also get the feeling I'm completely missing a logical-shortcut I could use.

Comment: @RoyalPotato Lexers don't parse. You've been told by three separate people that this is a parsing problem, not a lexical analysis problem.

Comment: @RoyalPotato: Your lexer doesn't need to know whether it is a method call or not.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, when I say "parse" I'm referring to parsing a stream of characters into tokens (i.e., an operation contained in the lexer). Sorry for any confusion that's caused.

Comment: Though to be clear, I do know a difference exists between the actual parsing phase and the lexical analysis.

Comment: [Here's](http://doai.io/10.1007/978-3-642-24452-0_5) another paper about parsing mixfix operators in Agda, written by Agda's implementors, I think.